# How to use an attribute inside an inner class?

Tags: ruby

I have the following code:

```
class Communication
  def initialize
    @messages = {:tx => [], :rx => []}
  end

  class Message
    def initialize (direction, name)
      if direction == "TX"
        @messages[:tx] << name #@messages dictionary is attribute from Communication class
      else
        @messages[:rx] << name #@messages dictionary is attribute from Communication class
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Every time I create a new Message object, I want the constructor to see the direction provided and insert it into it's correct key of dictionary "@messages" of Communication class. I am not sure how the class Message will distinguish @messages inside its constructor as its own attribute or an attribute from upper level class Communication. Would I be able to insert the values into @messages from the Message constructor? Or do I need to do it from the Communication class level?

Comment: _"dictionary "@messages" of Communication class"_ – the dictionary belongs to _instances_ of `Communication`, not the class itself. And each instance will have its own. If you want a "global" dictionary, you have to define it on the _class_ level or use a singleton class.

Answer (score 5):

> Would I be able to insert the values into `@messages` from the `Message` constructor?

Nope. Don't be fooled by the nesting. `Communication::Message` is its own standalone class. When you create an instance of it, you do **not** get an instance of `Communication` as a bonus.

For almost all practical purposes, treat them as if they were not nested. Nesting affects constant lookup path, but that's pretty much it.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that you might consider is to encapsulate message creation as a method in Communication.

```
class Communication
  def initialize
    @messages = {:tx => [], :rx => []}
  end

  class Message
    def initialize (direction, name)
      # Initialize the message
    end
  end

  def create_message(direction, name)
    if direction == "TX"
        @messages[:tx] << name #@messages dictionary is attribute from Communication class
      else
        @messages[:rx] << name #@messages dictionary is attribute from Communication class
    end
    return Message.new(direction, name)
  end
end
```

Comment: @krmckone it still makes sens to have Message as inner class correct? there is no chance to create a Message object without a Communication existing one.

Comment: @mareiou Right, I just didn't have it in the original snippet. It's back in now.

Comment: @mareiou: *There is no nested class*. Ruby doesn't have nested classes.